# how can i select dynamic type with linq from my Store procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, stored-procedures, entity-framework-5

Its simple:
i dont have a model/view model for this result. I dont want to have it.
I just want to call my Stored Procedure and make a dynamic type.
Something like that:

```
dynamic ceps = (from cep in context.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>("spLogradouro @pCEP, @pUF, @pLOCALIDADE, @pTIPOLOGRADOURO, @pLOGRADOURO", new SqlParameter("pCEP", filter), new SqlParameter("pUF", ""), new SqlParameter("pLOCALIDADE", ""), new SqlParameter("pTIPOLOGRADOURO", ""), new SqlParameter("pLOGRADOURO", ""))
                              select new 
                        {
                            property_one = name_of_my_column_of_this_stored_procedure_return

                        }).Single();
```

cant be that hard.

**EDIT**

inst what i was looking for, but achieve my goal doing this:

```
  CepContext context = new CepContext();
        JsonResult result = Json(new { Street = "", District = "", City = "", UF = "" });
        using (var cmd = context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
        {

            cmd.CommandText = "spLogradouro @pCEP, @pUF, @pLOCALIDADE, @pTIPOLOGRADOURO, @pLOGRADOURO";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("pCEP", filter));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("pUF", ""));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("pLOCALIDADE", ""));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("pTIPOLOGRADOURO", ""));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("pLOGRADOURO", ""));

            cmd.Connection.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();
                result = Json(new
                {
                    Street = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("log_logradouro")),
                    District = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("log_bairro")),
                    City = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("log_localidade")),
                    UF = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("log_uf"))
                });
            }
            cmd.Connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: at least say why you downvoted :(

Comment: don't care about downvotes , just ask and learn what you need :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not what i was looking for, but achieve my goal doing this:

```
  CepContext context = new CepContext();
        JsonResult result = Json(new { Street = "", District = "", City = "", UF = "" });
        using (var cmd = context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
        {

            cmd.CommandText = "spLogradouro @pCEP, @pUF, @pLOCALIDADE, @pTIPOLOGRADOURO, @pLOGRADOURO";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("pCEP", filter));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("pUF", ""));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("pLOCALIDADE", ""));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("pTIPOLOGRADOURO", ""));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("pLOGRADOURO", ""));

            cmd.Connection.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();
                result = Json(new
                {
                    Street = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("log_logradouro")),
                    District = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("log_bairro")),
                    City = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("log_localidade")),
                    UF = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("log_uf"))
                });
            }
            cmd.Connection.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always execute SQL via C# and read the result set into a dynamic object.

Comment: Hope this provides you with enough info.